# Why i don't have .jar?

Tags: java, jar

When download a file like "example.jar" the file isn't .jar is just a white file.
I tried finding an other .jar file from my java folder and Run As.. it but it just runned cmd for 1 second and then closed it.
Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "just a white file"? What do you mean by "and Run As..."? You haven't given *nearly* enough information here.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on

Answer (score 3):

You have to run it via your cmd with command:

```
 java -jar NameOfFile.jar
```

And you do not see the file extensions, because you most likely told windows in folder options to hide them.

Comment: +1 just because you managed to find ANY answer to that question. I have no idea what he's asking at all! You must have one excellent gibberish translator.